# You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am creating a simple plugin in WordPress. This is a simple form with three fields that will save data to a database table. The plugin is activated successfully, but when I fill the form and press button to submit, it shows me a blank screen with error:

```
You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.
```

I searched the Internet but did not find a solution.

Comment: The solution is located here: [Custom Wordpress Plugin: Sufficient Privelages Error][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136064/custom-wordpress-3-5-2-plugin-you-do-not-have-sufficient-permissions-to-access/18136893#18136893

Answer (score 0):

This is a HTTP 403 error; it means you're trying to access a directory that either doesn't exist or doesn't have an index file in it. Make sure the "action"-attribute of your form is pointing to the right file.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error. login to your phpadmin and access that DB. select "usermeta" table . Check meta key "_capabilities".
this  is defined in your wp_config. table prefix is CASE SENSITIVE. Check its value.

_capabilities will have its value a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}

table prefix "wp_" is not same as "Wp_". 
so edit the record in usermeta table and check your site.

tableprefix play a vital role in DB connection with WP frontend